# What security vulnerabilities will there be if I didn't protect the backend (Meteor official tutorial)?

Tags: meteor

I refer to the Meteor Official Tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

This code (at the frontend) is to add a private button. The button only appears beside the user's own tasks and when that user is logged in:

```
{{#if isOwner}}
  <button class="toggle-private">
    {{#if private}}
      Private
    {{else}}
      Public
    {{/if}}
  <button>
{{/if}}
```

The isOwner is defined as:

```
Template.task.helpers({
  isOwner() {
    return this.owner === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

This is the method to set tasks to private (at the backend):

```
'tasks.setPrivate' (taskId, setToPrivate) {
  check(taskId, String);
  check(setToPrivate, Boolean);

  if (task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorised');
  }

  Tasks.update(taskId, { $set: { private: setToPrivate }});
}
```

I understand that the inclusion of:

```
if (task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorised');
}
```

Will create an extra layer of protection. It can be made unnecessary, since the front-end will not show the private button anyways if the current user is not the owner of the tasks. I'm curious - what security vulnerabilities will there be if I did not include the above code at the back-end? How would an attacker exploit this vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can never trust the front-end. Anyone can edit it at execution. One just need to change your task helper isOwner to `return this.owner === true;` at execution and he is then seen as the owner.

In the [Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html) there is a good article about security, starting with:

> Securing a web application is all about understanding security domains and understanding the attack surface between these domains. In a Meteor app, things are pretty simple:
>
> Code that runs on the server can be trusted.
>
> Everything else: code that runs on the client, data sent through Method and publication arguments, etc, can’t be trusted.

Server is the only trusted part of your app, so you should always check on the server. Client-side check is mainly done for a better user experience.

Comment: to add on: anyone can open a browser console and call your Meteor methods, logged in or not. when you're writing your server code, ruthlessly check inputs and operations to ensure whoever is calling is properly authorized for the action. i check Every Little Thing and log extensively.